# Why do I get this arbitrary syntax error?

Tags: glsl, raytracing, shadertoy

I'm learning GLSL, and I thought it might be a fun project to build a simple raytracer. I can't figure out why I get a weird syntax error on this function:

```
vec3 rayAt(in ray r, in float t)
{
    return r.o + t*r.d;
}
```

For context, `r.o` and `r.d` are components of this struct:

```
struct ray
{
    vec3 o;
    vec3 d;
}
```

Edit: I'm writing this on shadertoy, and the specific error I get is `'vec3' : syntax error`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: 'vec3' : syntax error - What is the line of code directly before `vec3`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/hkN8uPPf

Comment: missing `;` (`struct { ... } ;`)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does this mean? which line exactly?

Comment: @Kai What Rabbid76 is pointing out is that every `class`,`struct` or `union` declaration in C/C++ needs to end with `;` because C/C++  is expected variable list declarations before the `;` if you write `struct T { int a; }` the C/C++ is considering whatever that follows to be a variable of type `T` until next `;` Your `struct ray` is missing the `;` after its ending bracket `}` so just put a `;` there `};`  For compiler its the same as difference between `int i` and `int i;`